# Show random texts from a .txt file but only once per IP address

Tags: php, html, random

Here is my php code that checks random.txt file for texts and randomly show one of them.

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "random.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
?>
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ); ?>" size="36">
```

Here is what inside my random.txt file.

```
Jack
Binsky
Igor
Ivan
Eva
```

I want my code to show this names to a visitor only once. It means if someone visit my webpage from an IP address, the page will show a name randomly from the .txt file. But it won't show that name second time for that IP address if the visitor reloads the webpage.

How can I do that?

Comment: you would have to log IP, and the name shown, and check that before deciding what to show. Of course you know IP != person.

Comment: @tim I know but I need help to code it.